# "frozen" is not definedPylance (reportUndefinedVariable)

Tags: python-3.x, pyright

I'm using pylance on VScode for type checking my Python code. It is having trouble with the frozen argument of dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class DataStoreConfig():
  store_id: str
  bucket_name: str
  prefix: str
```

Pylance complains with this error: `"frozen" is not definedPylance (reportUndefinedVariable)`

When I navigate to `dataclasses.pyi`, this is what I see for dataclass:

```
@overload
def dataclass(_cls: Type[_T]) -> Type[_T]: ...
@overload
def dataclass(_cls: None) -> Callable[[Type[_T]], Type[_T]]: ...
@overload
def dataclass(
    *, init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., eq: bool = ..., order: bool = ..., unsafe_hash: bool = ..., frozen: bool = ...
) -> Callable[[Type[_T]], Type[_T]]: ...
```

So it seems like it is not picking the right overloaded method. Anyway to guide it?

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Comment: This issue is reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/322. They are working on a fix.